# Why would C files end in /*[]*/

Tags: c, coding-style

I am looking through some proprietary source code: sample programs in using a library.

The code is written in C and C++, using make for build system.

Each and every file ends in a commented out `[]`: `/*[]*/` for source files and `#[]#` for makefiles. What could be the reason for this?

The code is compiled for ARM with GCC, using extensions.

Comment: That would probably for `vi`.

Comment: I won't call that a coding style, and I would guess that it is not standard C. Lines starting with `#` are often preprocessor directives, and `[]#` is not a standard one. Are you sure that `#[]#` is really the last line of each file?

Comment: My guess is that the makefile system uses those lines somewhere.  If the code has old enough C code, it couldn't necessarily count on // comments, so # would be a way to add a single line of non-code, and the precompiler would filter it out.  Maybe it's for building a dependency tree, or something?  My hunch would be to look through the makefile.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I was in error: editing the question.

Comment: Try to compile with `gcc -Wall` and upgrade your GCC to a recent version (current one is 4.8). Also use an hex editor (or `od -cx`) to be sure of the last few bytes in your files.....

Comment: (FYI, I've made your title consistent with your text.)  The C compiler will ignore `/*[]*/` just like any other comment, and Make will likewise ignore `#[]#`. I suspect this is a (vacuous) annotation for some sort of IDE.  Are there any files where there's something inside the square brackets? What IDE was used to write the code originally?

Comment: No idea how the code is written. I will try with `-Wall` and `-pedantic`, but not immediately.

Comment: Maybe some tool (perhaps a version control system) is transforming the `[]` into something else in the last line.....

Answer (score 6):

It is most likely a place holder for some sort of automatic expansion.

Typically something like macrodef (or one of the source code control filters) would expand such items to contain some relevant text.  As typically only the comment-protected brackets would expand, the comments would remain in place, protecting the source code from actual expanded items at compilation time.

However, what you are currently looking at is probably the outer containing brackets with all of the internal expansions removed.  This may have been done during a code migration from one source code control system to another.  Although such an idea is highly speculative, it does not appear that they took the effort to migrate expansion items, instead of just removing them.

Answer (score 0):

On one project I used to work, every C source file contained a comment at the very end:

```
/* End of file */
```

The reason for that was the gcc warning

```
Warning : No new line at end of file
```

So we had this comment (with a new line after it) to be sure people do not write after the comment :)

Comment: That makes no sense! People will still be able to delete the new line at the end of that comment, as long as their editor allows it.

Comment: That's a good idea, and I thought of mentioning it too; but, it fails to account for why the make files have the same style of comments.  Make files do not get compiled, and so they will not get `gcc` to emit a compiler warning.

Comment: @rodrigo Sure, but they see the comment, and kind of dont write 'after the end of file'. It worked indeed.

Comment: @EdwinBuck We had this for scripts as well, it helped merging branches with our old ClearCase.